# How Response Generation works in RASA core?

Tags: machine-learning, chatbot, spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I'm quite new to Chatbots and started using RASA as a framework. And wondering which method RASA use as their response generation technique. (NLG)

Theoretically, there are two types of NLG techniques:

1. Template driven NLG
2. Advanced NLG - Neural nets and ML

So, in RASA what method they use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RASA stack is flexible enough to support both use cases.

The documentation (v: 0.10.3) for your question can be found at: http://www.rasa.com/docs/core/responses/

## TL;DR

RASA offers a **built-in** **templated based** NLG. However, it also allows you to connect to an **external HTTP server** for NLG. What happens in that server is up to you, and it could be a **neural net based** NLG server, but that needs to be done by you.

## Template driven NLG

From the docs:

> The default format is, to include the utterances into your domain
>   file. This file then contains references to all your custom actions,
>   available entities, slots and intents.

One section of your *domain* file will include a **templates** section. Here is an example from the docs:

```
templates:
  utter_greet:
    - "hey there {name}!"    # variable will be filled by slot with the same name or by custom code
  utter_goodbye:
    - "goodbye "
    - "bye bye "              # multiple templates will allow the bot to randomly pick from them
  utter_default:
    - "default message"
```

## Advanced NLG - Neural nets and ML

From the docs:

> Retraining the bot, just to change the text copy can be suboptimal for
>   some workflows. That’s why Core also allows you to outsource the
>   response generation and separate it from the dialogue learning.
>
> The bot will still learn to predict actions and to react to user input
>   based on past dialogues, but the responses it sends back to the user
>   are generated outside of Rasa Core.
>
> If the bot wants to send a message to the user, it will call an
>   external HTTP server with a POST request. To configure this endpoint,
>   you need to create an endpoints.yml and pass it either to the run or
>   server script.

The core will contact your server with information from the the conversation, including the user utterance, intent and slots filled. Your server then would have a neural net based NLG (**developed by you**) which would return the text that the bot should display to the user.